# Text to image on web server

Tags: java, image-processing

I'm wondering if there is a way to create images out of text in a Java web app.

I'm using GWT to design a web app, and would like to allow some administration so that a small number of things could be edited by someone without a ton of savvy and not require a migration. This would be, say, menu headings, which I would otherwise create out of text in (e.g.) Photoshop, and include in my ear. Instead I want to allow an administrator to add some text, and I'd have some code to convert this to an image, using some specified formatting, for "nice" presentation.

As an example, the administrator might want to add a "news" page. So he will enter `News` and it will come out looking like: [image: News Image]

Am I making sense? Is this something that is done? Are there libraries available for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://www.java-forums.org/java-2d/1571-writing-text-into-image-save.html) explains the concept pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanted to create Vector graphic then yes. You could also convert image into base64 string to store the image and reverse back loading at client.

Comment: Is there a library you're referring to that will convert text to graphics?